# Cleaning(Re.sub) when a text has too many new lines in python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a text I want to clean. The problem is that there is too many new lines. When I open the text using `text=open(file, 'r')` and `text=text.read()`then I see too many new lines that is very difficult to clean. I want to remove the whole following text.

```
    How
Can I Help?
     Keep 
in Touch
     Working 
for You
     Briefing 
Room
 Meeting 
You
     F.A.Q.
```

I use `re.sub` to remove them. Because there are too many new lines I need 11 lines of `re.sub` command. Even worse, `How`, `Working`, `You` or `Briefing` are too general so they can be removed from the body even I don't want to erase them. I can use re.sub command like,

```
remove1 = 'How'
remove2 = 'Can I Help'
remove3 = 'in Touch'
remove4 = 'Working'
remove5 = 'Briefing'
remove6 = 'Room'
remove7 = 'Meeting'
remove8 = 'You'
remove9 = 'F.A.Q'

text = re.sub(quant1, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant2,'', text)
text = re.sub(quant3, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant4, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant5, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant6, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant7, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant8, '', text)
text = re.sub(quant9, '', text)
```

Is there a better way to clean this? I don't want to do it line by line. I want to remove two lines `How Can I Help?` at once. I don't want to include too general words like `How`.

If I use `text.readlines()`, the outcome looks like the following.

```
'\tHow\r\n', 'Can I Help?\r\n', ' \t Keep \r\n', 'in Touch\r\n', ' \t Working \r\n',
 'for You\r\n', ' \t Briefing \r\n', 'Room\r\n', ' \t Meeting \r\n', 'You\r\n', ' \t F.A.Q.\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|`, from the document:

> `'|'`
>
> A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression that will match either A or B.
>
> An arbitrary number of REs can be separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside groups (see below) as well.
>
> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted.
>
> This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match. In other words, the '|' operator is never greedy.
>
> To match a literal `'|'`, use `\|`, or enclose it inside a character class, as in `[|]`.

So as the document says, `|` match `foo|bar` and `foo`, and we can simply use `bar` get `'|'.join(['foo', 'bar'])`.

So you could try:

```
text = re.sub('|'.join([remove1, remove2, remove3, remove4, remove5, remove6
, remove7, remove8, remove9]), '', text)
```

Comment: Thank you! `'|'` is a great solution. But the problem is when I do `'|'.join(['How','Can I Help'])`, then every `How` in my document will be erased. I only want to erase `How` that has `Can I Help` on the next line. I showed only a part of my text. In the body of my text, I have a bunch of `How` that I don't want to remove. I tried `'&'`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user3077008: Hmm...what about use `How(?=\s+Can I Help\?)` instead?